# Debugging #lang sicp in DrRacket

Tags: scheme, racket, sicp

I am happily using DrRacket with the inbuilt SICP language (https://docs.racket-lang.org/sicp-manual/SICP_Language.html) to work through SICP.

However, I'm unable to use the DrRacket debugger with the SICP language.
A simple test example,

```
#lang racket
(define (test x)
  (* x x))
(test (test (test 2)))
```

debugs happily, and I can step through and see 'x' being updated etc.

However, using the SICP language as follows

```
#lang sicp
(define (test x)
  (* x x))
(test (test (test 2)))
```

results in an error:

```
Library/Racket/7.5/pkgs/sicp/sicp/main.rkt:67:32: ?: cannot bind from tainted syntax in: (quote #%kernel)
```

Does anyone know what the problem might be? I've not really had to use the debugging yet, but I would quite like knowing that it's there if I do want to use it.

Comment: This bug has been fixed and will appear in Racket 7.6. You can try it out here: https://snapshot.racket-lang.org/

Comment: Thanks - I'll probably wait for 7.6 to come out as I'm not in desperate need of it.
As an aside, thankyou for your work on the SICP collection!